# Common mistakes in ER Modelling?

Tags: java, c#, php, database, entity-relationship

I need to practice ER modelling for the exams, keep in mind there is not gonna be any third party tool, it would have to be done manually on paper :(
Is there any recommendations to avoid mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you have already done some searching on the web.  Just a couple of pointers:

- Don't forget to annotate your cardinality (one is to many, etc).
- If your diagram goes into showing attributes, don't forget to show the Primary Key and Foreign Keys.

Stumbled across this nice PDF article which has a lot more detail:
http://www.cis.drexel.edu/faculty/song/courses/info%20605/appendix/AppendixA.PDF

Comment: That is true, thanks reaanb.  I removed that statement about the naming of the entity and relationship.

Answer (score 0):

The key, the whole key and nothing but the key.

Remember it's more then just drawing pretty pictures on a page.  You need to look at your definitions and make sure their dependancy aligns with the above